# Cup product property (proof doubt)

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

So i am having a little trouble understanding this proof (sorry for posting a picture i tried to write it but my tikz wasnt working for some reason) [image]

Now my question is is he trying to prove that the cup product $-\cup v$ will be a morphism between the short exact sequence of chain complexes, and then we can use the fact about the naturality of the connecting homomorphism with the long exact sequence of co-homology ? Also i think he uses $\delta$ to mean two thing that is the connecting homomorphism and also the differential in the complexes , am I right about this or am I confusing something ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think tikz works in mathjax.